# How to create tabs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four different blocks with categories as you can see in the image, and what I want to do is the following:

Initially, I only want to see the content of "fryking", then if I click on a different block such as "Halaal", its content must be displayed underneath, and the content of fryking and so other boxes need to disappear.

How could I do that?

The following is what I have so far:

```css
#menu_list {
  display: flex;
}
.box{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
.one{
  background: red;
}
.two{
  background: blue;
}
.three{
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<section id="menu_list">
  <div class=" box one active fryking">
      FRYKING
  </div>
  <div class="box two">
    HALAAL
  </div>
  <div class="box three">
  
  </div>
</section>
<section id="menus"> 
  <div class="fryking active" id="fryking">
    <h3 class="cat_title">Combos</h3>
    <div class="cat_content">
      <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of </p>
    </div><h3 class="cat_title">FIsh &amp; Chips</h3>
    <div class="cat_content">
      <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?<br>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>        
  </div>

  <div class="halaal" id="halaal">
    <h3 class="cat_title">Masala Dosa</h3>
    <div class="cat_content">
      <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of “de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum” (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero,</p>
    </div>       
  </div>
</section>
```

I saw this [pen here](https://codepen.io/cssjockey/pen/jGzuK) but the structure of my project is different and I cannot really change because it's a WordPress site.

Answer (score 0):

> I saw this pen here but the structure of my project is different and I cannot really change cause its a wordpress site

I don't understand what's the problems with the structure ?

If you want to create a manual tabs you can create a css class like that :

```
.no-display{
     display : none;
}
```

And in your jquery you just have to play with the class name :

```
$('.ul.tabs').removeClass('no-display'); 
$('.ul.tabs').addClass('no-display');
```

Easy and fast,

Peace

Comment: It's working, but I will not do your work for you, just say how do it

Answer (score 0):

Check the below. I added a bit of CSS to hide/display the correct content. Things could be more efficient if you could change the HTML.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".one", function() {
  $("#menus > div").removeClass("active");
  $("#menus > div.fryking").addClass("active");
});

$("body").on("click", ".two", function() {
  $("#menus > div").removeClass("active");
  $("#menus > div.halaal").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
#menu_list {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
}

.three {
  background: black;
}

#menus>div {
  display: none;
}

#menus>div.active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="menu_list">
  <div class=" box one active fryking">
    FRYKING
  </div>
  <div class="box two">
    HALAAL
  </div>
  <div class="box three">

  </div>
</section>
<section id="menus">
  <div class="fryking active" id="fryking">
    <h3 class="cat_title">Combos</h3>
    <div class="cat_content">
      <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
        up one of </p>
    </div>
    <h3 class="cat_title">FIsh &amp; Chips</h3>
    <div class="cat_content">
      <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?<br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
        a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="halaal" id="halaal">
    <h3 class="cat_title">Masala Dosa</h3>
    <div class="cat_content">
      <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
        up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of “de Finibus
        Bonorum et Malorum” (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero,</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It works and I very much appreciate the support. I wish I could change the html to make it more flexible

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

  $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
  $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

  $(this).addClass('current');
  $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
 })

})
```

```css
body{
 margin-top: 100px;
 font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
 line-height: 1.6
}
.container{
 width:600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}



ul.tabs{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
}
ul.tabs li{
 background: none;
 color: #222;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

ul.tabs li.current{
 background: #ededed;
 color: #222;
}

.tab-content{
 display: none;
 background: #ededed;
 padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current{
 display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
    <div class="container">
    
     <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
      
     </ul>
    
     <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
      <h4>CONTENT -1</h4>
       Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
     </div>
     <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
      <h4>CONTENT -2</h4>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
     </div>
     <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
      <h4>CONTENT -3</h4>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
     </div>
    </div><!-- container -->
```

HERE are more references:

[Link one](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp)

[link two](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)